# Replace something with a string and sed -e

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I want to replace multiples phrases in a file using sed -e. The problem is that I want to replace certain phrases with a string is there anyway to do this? Because when I do this using

```
sed -e 's/foo/$bar/' -e 's/some/$text/' file.whatever
```

then it does not have any effect...

Comment: It will only replace within the file if you use the `-i` flag. Otherwise the changes are shown on STDOUT.

Comment: sed -i -e 's/foo/$bar/' -e 's/some/$text/' file.whatever ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say *with a string* I believe you mean **with a variable**. If that is the case, simply surround the `sed` command with **double-quotes** instead of single-quotes.  The former will allow for variable expansion, the latter will not.

```
sed -e "s/foo/$bar/" -e "s/some/$text/" file.whatever
```